# web part empty list

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I am very new to sharepoint and specially sharepoint designer but somewhat experienced  ASP.NET developer.

I have a problem in SharePoint Designer 2007 that it does not show me any web part at all (even when a web part zone is inserted and selected).

How can I make sure that my settings are correct and application is faulty and how can I make it show the web parts?

My second question is about ability to write C# code in designer. I have seen some online tutorials on creating a C# script and coding it there but I suppose there must be a more reasonable way.

Comment: you should split up this question into two seperate questions, and edit the title to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

SharePoints default security model will not allow inline code compilation in pages, and you cannot do code-behind in SharePoint Designer. If you want to add code for pages you need Visual Studio.

FYI - you should not ask two questions in one post. Please edit your post and seperate your questions.